# Remove all XML elements with no attributes C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I would like to know how to remove all elements from an xml file which do not have a first attribute of type ***name*** or ***ref***. The child elements that DO contain a first attribute of the required type must stay even if the parent has been deleted and they should just be moved up in the hierarchy

For example, if this is the input file:

```
<xs:element name="Body" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="Client" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element ref="Risk" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element ref="Claim" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element ref="Complaint" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element ref="ClientFee" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element ref="User" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I would expect the following output:

```
<xs:element name="Body" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element ref="Client" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element ref="Risk" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element ref="Claim" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element ref="Complaint" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element ref="ClientFee" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element ref="User" minOccurs="0" />
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example this way:

```
 void RemoveRecurence(XElement e) {
      foreach(var child in e.Elements()) {
           RemoveRecurence(child);
      }

      if (e.Attribute("name") == null && e.Attribute("ref") == null) {
           e.ReplaceWith(e.Elements());            
      }
 }
```

Comment: Edited a little, first variant was for total removing such elemnts, this variant will replace them with children instead

Comment: You need to switch round the ordering - recurse *first*, *then* potentially do the `ReplaceWith`. Otherwise `e`'s parent will have changed, and you won't be referring to the same elements. I've just tried it, and after switching the ordering it's fine.